# Adding zlib library to project breaks msvc

Tags: c++, zlib

I'm a little stuck. Its quite "large" project and I need to add zlib to it, but all my attempts have failed.
I have build zlib from source using msvc.
I'm using

```
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
```

and then I use this for my linking > ZLIB::ZLIB

It appear to link fine, but when I try to compile I get this >

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(209): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'const _Elem' to 'long'
        with
        [
            _Elem=QChar
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(209): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(208): note: while compiling class template member function 'long std::_Char_traits<_Elem,long>::to_int_type(const _Elem &) noexcept'
        with
        [
            _Elem=QChar
        ]
```

And many more errors that came out of it. As far as I can tell the issues file is > `zconf.h`
Once that gets added, everything breaks.
Are there any flags/stuff I have to configure to not cause a total havoc with my system?

Comment: Could be the order of your includes.

Comment: My guess is that zconf.h is doing a #define of some keyword that also appears in Microsoft's headers.   You might have a look at lines 208-209 of xstring.h and see if there are any keywords used on those lines that also appear in #defines in zconf.h.  (if that is the case, you might be able to avoid the problem by #including the zlib headers *after* all of the Win32 headers)

Comment: I got it solved, a completly unrelated error creeped in in my source that cause everything to go bananas. Bad variable pass esentially that did not get flagged by ide/etc. Dramma for nothing. zlib works.